# Error with strcpy in C programming

Tags: c, string

I have an exam next month and I'm playing around with everything that isn't clear to me. I created a function that simply allows the user to input a string and returns the string and its length as parameters. I'm using strcpy to copy the string in the variable declared inside the function into the first parameter parameter but the program crashes when it arrives at that point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

void insertString(char orig[], int *len);

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    char str[MAX] = {0};

    insertString(str[MAX], &length);

    printf("You have inserted: %s", str); 
    printf("The length of the stream you entered is: %d", length);

    return 0;
}

void insertString(char orig[], int *len)
{
    char str1[MAX];
    printf("Insert your string: ");
    fgets(str1, MAX, stdin);
    strcpy(orig, str1);
    *len = strlen(str1) - 1;
}
```

Comment: In real programs, you should use `strncpy` instead

Comment: So what do you think `str[MAX]` is passing into `insertString`?

Comment: @fotanus: in real programs strncpy() should be avoided.

Comment: @wildplasser how should you copy a string so?

Comment: Either use memcpy() + manually add a terminating nul, or use strcpy(). strncpy() is *not safe* and only gives false hope to people who feel insecure.

Comment: [Explanation of *why* `strncpy()` is not the way to go.](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insertString(str[MAX], &length);]
```

passes a character (that too out of bounds).

You wanted to pass a pointer to the array:

```
insertString(str, &length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line `insertString(str[MAX], &length);` to `insertString(str, &length);`

The former is trying to pass a character (surprised this didn't give you a warning) and the latter is passing the pointer to the start of the buffer, which is what, I think, you want...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
insertString(str[MAX], &length);
```

to

```
insertString(str, &length);
```

You want to pass array of characters not just one character.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[MAX] = {0};

insertString(str[MAX], &length);
```

For the matter, when you do `char str[MAX]`  with `MAX` as 100 . It creates an array with subscripts `0` to `99`

`str[MAX]` does not exist. {Atleast you are not allowed to access it}

`insertString(str, &length);` will do good, it passes an array

Answer (score 0):

you should either use

```
insertString(str, &length);
```

or

```
insertString(&str[0], &length);
```